# WordPress Связать товары

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Upsells привязывает один товар к другому. А есть какая то возможность двусторонней привязки? Привязал один товар к другому и автоматом в другом товаре прописался первый? Или может плагин какой? Не могу найти.
Ситуация такая, есть продукт и есть подходящие к нему запчасти. Соответственно, они должны быть связаны. Как реализовать лучше всего?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете также в товаре получить список upsell относительно upsell главного товаров

Примерный код :

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );

function custom_woocommerce_upsell_display() {
    
    global $product;

    $upsell_ids = $product->get_upsell_ids( 'edit' );

    foreach ( $upsell_ids as $upsell_id_product_id ) {
    
      $upsell_product = wc_get_product( $upsell_id_product_id );
      
      //выводим товар
      
      //upsell относительно привязанных товаров

      $upsell_upsell_ids = $upsell_product->get_upsell_ids( 'edit' );
      
      foreach ( $upsell_upsell_ids as $upsell_upsell_id_product_id ) {
        
            $upsell_upsell_product = wc_get_product( $upsell_upsell_id_product_id );
            
            //выводим товар
      }
    }
}
```

Визуальный гайд по хукам страницы товара https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: Этот код прописать в function.php? А на какой хук?

Comment: @MacKlaud скорректировал ответ

Comment: Благодарю! Особенно за гайд.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете WordPress с EDD или WooCommerce, это отличный плагин Upsell! Это позволяет автоматически генерировать целевые допродажи каждому из ваших клиентов и посетителей. https://www.pluginsandsnippets.com/downloads/upsellmaster/

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).